# Virtual MIDI output not working on AudioKit 5 with Xcode 12 and iOS 14

Tags: swift, midi, audiokit, ios14, xcode12

I'm using Xcode 12 beta 6 with v5-master branch of AudioKit build from source.

This code works to send MIDI data:

```swift
    var midi = AKMIDI()
    midi.openOutput()
    midi.sendControllerMessage(MIDIByte(10), value: MIDIByte(64), channel: MIDIChannel(1))
```

But I need to create a virtual MIDI output like this:

```swift
    var midi = AKMIDI()
    midi.createVirtualOutputPort(name: "Virtual out")
    midi.openOutput()
    midi.sendControllerMessage(MIDIByte(10), value: MIDIByte(64), channel: MIDIChannel(1))
```

As soon as I add the line `midi.createVirtualOutputPort(name: "Virtual out")`, it's causing the next errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for AKDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKSoundpipeKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for AKDSPBase in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      vtable for AKSoundpipeKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
      vtable for AKDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKDSPKernel.o)
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "std::length_error::~length_error()", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "typeinfo for std::length_error", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _createAKParameterAutomation in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ____ZN27AKParameterAutomationHelper23automationObserverBlockEv_block_invoke in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::reconcileRecordedSegments() in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::enable_if<(__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::value) && (is_constructible<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::iterator_traits<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::reference>::value), std::__1::__wrap_iter<AKParameterAutomationPoint*> >::type std::__1::vector<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationPoint> >::insert<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>(std::__1::__wrap_iter<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::list<std::__1::pair<float, double>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<float, double> > >::list(std::__1::list<std::__1::pair<float, double>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<float, double> > > const&) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::pair<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, void*>*, long>, bool> std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<unsigned long long, std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, std::__1::less<unsigned long long>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData> > >::__emplace_unique_key_args<unsigned long long, std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<unsigned long long const&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(unsigned long long const&, std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<unsigned long long const&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__split_buffer<AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData::RecordedSegment, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData::RecordedSegment>&>::__split_buffer(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData::RecordedSegment>&) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::mutex::try_lock()", referenced from:
      ____ZN27AKParameterAutomationHelper19renderObserverBlockEv_block_invoke in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for AKDSPBase in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      typeinfo for DSPKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKOutputBuffered in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      ____ZN27AKParameterAutomationHelper23automationObserverBlockEv_block_invoke in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::reconcileRecordedSegments() in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::enable_if<(__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::value) && (is_constructible<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::iterator_traits<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::reference>::value), std::__1::__wrap_iter<AKParameterAutomationPoint*> >::type std::__1::vector<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationPoint> >::insert<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>(std::__1::__wrap_iter<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::enable_if<(__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::value) && (is_constructible<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::iterator_traits<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::reference>::value), void>::type std::__1::vector<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationPoint> >::assign<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>(AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::vector<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationPoint> >::__vallocate(unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::vector<AKAutomationEvent, std::__1::allocator<AKAutomationEvent> >::__vallocate(unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::vector<AudioBufferList*, std::__1::allocator<AudioBufferList*> >::__vallocate(unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      ...
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
  "std::__1::mutex::lock()", referenced from:
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::play(AVAudioTime const*, double) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::stop() in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::enableRecording(unsigned long long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::disableRecording(unsigned long long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::addPoints(unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::setPoints(unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::clearRange(unsigned long long, double, double) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::mutex::unlock()", referenced from:
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::play(AVAudioTime const*, double) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::stop() in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::enableRecording(unsigned long long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::disableRecording(unsigned long long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::addPoints(unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::setPoints(unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::clearRange(unsigned long long, double, double) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::mutex::~mutex()", referenced from:
      _deleteAKParameterAutomation in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
  "vtable for std::length_error", referenced from:
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKDSPBase.o)
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _deleteAKParameterAutomation in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::reconcileRecordedSegments() in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::enable_if<(__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::value) && (is_constructible<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::iterator_traits<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::reference>::value), std::__1::__wrap_iter<AKParameterAutomationPoint*> >::type std::__1::vector<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationPoint> >::insert<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>(std::__1::__wrap_iter<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::enable_if<(__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::value) && (is_constructible<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::iterator_traits<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>::reference>::value), void>::type std::__1::vector<AKParameterAutomationPoint, std::__1::allocator<AKParameterAutomationPoint> >::assign<AKParameterAutomationPoint const*>(AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      _AKParameterAutomationGetRenderObserver in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ___destroy_helper_block_ea8_32s40r72c59_ZTSNSt3__16vectorI17AKAutomationEventNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEE in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<unsigned long long, std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, std::__1::less<unsigned long long>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationHelper::ParameterData>, void*>*) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ...
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _createAKParameterAutomation in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::play(AVAudioTime const*, double) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::stop() in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::enableRecording(unsigned long long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::disableRecording(unsigned long long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::addPoints(unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      AKParameterAutomationHelper::setPoints(unsigned long long, AKParameterAutomationPoint const*, unsigned long) in AudioKit(AKParameterAutomation-e7cbeb9f2f297ebe0ad57bddadf7449b377f8b2566468df168fd440392e50064.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in
```

This was working fine with AudioKit 4.X, Xcode 11 and iOS 13.

Any ideas on how to proceed? It looks like some weird c++ linking issue.

Comment: Just FYI Xcode 12 was released yesterday, maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: I'm aware of that… From Apple downloads page: "For development on macOS Big Sur or to support Apple silicon, continue to use Xcode 12 beta 6." I'm on Big Sur, so I believe I need to stay with beta 6. But I will try with the new version, thanks for the advice.